# Does mocha need to import my actual javascript code in order to test it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I'm new to code testing and I'm trying to test with Mocha some functions I've written in Javascript. The problem is that I'm not sure whether or not I should somehow import my script.js (where my functions are coded) to test/test.js.

If I run random tests like below it passes the test,

```
describe('Triangle', function(){
    it('should evaluate whether input is number or not', function(){
        var foo = '';
        expect('foo').to.be.NaN;
    });
});
```

but Triangle is a function in my script.js so I don't know whether or not this is actually testing that file. Or maybe I'm getting this wrong and testing is not actually having the test file and my script linked somehow. Could anybody help? Cheers

***Edit***

I've edited it to show how my folder is ser:

```
 |node_modules
 |test
  --test.js
 script.js
 testrunner.html
```

I'm runnning testrunner.html and it reads the tests in test.js. I didn't find any explanation on how to make test.js read my script.js so that it can actually be tested.

Comment: How else than by importing your code are you going to be able to call the functions that you've written??

Comment: Yes, to test code, you need to import it, call it, and check if the results of those calls match the expectations that you as developer have about your code. Mocha doesn't know about your code at all.

Comment: @Louis I've updated the question to show my folder and another question.

Comment: @robertklep I've updated the question to show my folder and another question.

Comment: @PauloGabriel since you tagged your question with [tag:node.js]: you can run Mocha as a command line utility, without the need for an HTML file or running the test in your browser: `mocha test/test.js`. In `test.js`, you load `script.js` as a regular Node module: `var Triangle = require('../script.js')`

Comment: @robertklep ok, via command line I get this when I load script.js as you mentioned: `ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulogabriel/Desktop/Testing/Working/Testing v.3 - Array Test/script.js:1:78) `

Comment: @PauloGabriel okay, so you do need to run the tests in your browser since it depends on the DOM :) In that case, you need to load `script.js` as a regular script before `test.js` (with `<script>` tags).

Comment: @robertklep done! Now it works. Thank you, mate!

Comment: @robertklep so, apparently I was mistaken and it didn't work. I'm running and passing tests, but if I simply enter a crazy function name will pass either way. :(

Comment: @PauloGabriel it might be worthwhile to create a new question for that specifically, showing (some of) the code you want to test and the test code.